# Dependency issue after cloning repo

Tags: node.js, angular, npm

I recently changed workstations so i decided to clone my Angular4 Project repo to the new workstation.
After cloning process i ran:

```
npm install
```

This is to get all the node_modules required.
In turn has resulted in a large number of missing PEER DEPENDENCIES.

Instead of doing the individual npm install for each missing dependency is there a better (or proper way of doing this)?

I've also tried

```
rm node_modules -Recurse -Force
npm cache clear
npm install
```

Still no luck.

**EDIT 1:**

npm version 3.10.10

Nodejs version 6.11.0

**EDIT 2: Example of failed dependencies**

```
+-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/common@4.2.4
+-- @angular/compiler@4.2.4
+-- @angular/compiler-cli@4.2.4
| +-- @angular/tsc-wrapped@4.2.4
| | `-- tsickle@0.21.6
| +-- minimist@1.2.0
| `-- reflect-metadata@0.1.10
+-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/core@4.2.4
+-- @angular/flex-layout@2.0.0-rc.1
+-- @angular/forms@4.2.4
+-- @angular/http@4.2.4
+-- @angular/material@2.0.0-beta.7
+-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/platform-browser@4.2.4
+-- @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@4.2.4
+-- @angular/platform-server@4.2.4
| +-- parse5@3.0.2
```

Comment: Can you provide node and npm version

Comment: @ManjeetThakur done

Comment: Are *all* relevant packages in your package.json file?

Comment: @nadavvadan yup. First thing i checked.

Answer (score 0):

With NPM v3 they removed the automatic installation of peer dependencies, so the only thing you can do is install them yourself.

Here's a good article that explains the problem:

https://codingwithspike.wordpress.com/2016/01/21/dealing-with-the-deprecation-of-peerdependencies-in-npm-3/

Comment: Thanks, i think i found a solution that so far seems to be working